# Error de rutas al subir proyecto a hosting compartido. (Laravel 5.4)

Tags: laravel

Subí mi proyecto a un hosting compartido y muestra sin problemas el index.php pero al hacer click en un enlace no me redirige a la pagina que debería sino que me muestra error 404 indicando que no existe la pagina.

Segun e leido puede ser un problema del htaccess, les dejo aqui mi archivo:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Actualmente tengo los archivos de la carpeta public en la carpeta raíz del hosting (public_html).

Comment: Me pasa esto que comentas.
Como soluciono que no tenga que poner lo de index.php/ruta?
Yo he probado a editar el htaccess y dar permisos a todas las carpetas, pero nada

Answer (score 1):

¿Los permisos de escritura en los directorios `/storage` y `/bootstrap/cache` están debidamente actualizados? Se debe permitir la escritura en dichos directorios y adicionalmente configurar la key de la aplicación usando artisan key:generate. Como referencia te dejo la documentación donde habla de la configuración necesaria: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation#configuration

También podrías revisar que el módulo Rewrite de Apache esté habilitado.

Por último te sugiero probar si las rutas funconan debidamente usando, por ejemplo: `public/index.php/ruta-prueba`. Esto lo menciono porque a veces no funciona usar, por ejemplo: `public/ruta-prueba`

Answer (score 1):

Guiándome de la respuesta de arriba revise la documentación de Laravel y vi que el archivo .htaccess es el que da las rutas sin necesidad de una url así que supuse que se pudo dañar el archivo en la subida al cpanel. así que lo subí de nuevo y lo reemplace y me funciono ahí te dejo ese dato ojala te sirva. Mi proveedor de hosting es hosgator.